# sum with conditional grouping

Tags: sql, sql-server, group-by, sql-server-2008-r2, sum

I have 2 tables: Departments and Sales.  In my department table I have a labor department id and the id of the sales department it is associated to.  I also want to allow a department's sales to "rollup" up to another department.  I need help with the query to "rollup" the sales.

Here are the tables:

```
TABLE = Departments
LaborDeptid | AssociatedSalesDept | RollUpTo
1                    101              0   
2                    102              0
3                    103              1
4                    104              0

TABLE = Sales
Date      | Sales | SalesDept
1/1/2014    10.00     101 
1/1/2014    10.00     101
1/1/2014    10.00     102
1/1/2014    10.00     102
1/1/2014    10.00     103
1/1/2014    10.00     103
1/1/2014    10.00     104
1/1/2014    10.00     104
```

Here is the output I would like:

```
OUTPUT
Date      | LaborDept | TotalSales
1/1/2014       1         40.00
1/1/2014       2         20.00
1/1/2014       4         20.00
```

As you can see, labor department 1 includes sales for sales department 101 and 103.  I have no idea how to do this, though.  The query to sum by day, by department is easy enough:

```
select 
    Date,
    LaborDept,
    sum(sales) as TotalSales
from sales s
inner join departments d on s.SalesDept = d.AssociatedSalesDept 
group by Date,LaborDept`
```

but how would I do the "rollup"?  I tried putting a case statement in the join like so:

```
select 
    sum(sales) as TotalSales,
    Date,
    LaborDept
from sales s
inner join departments d on s.SalesDept = case when d.RollUpTo <> 0 then 
(select AssociatedSalesDept 
from departments
where d.RollUpTo = LaborDeptID)
else d.AssociatedSalesDept end
group by Date,LaborDept
```

but that just dropped the 103 sales department all together.  And it doesn't seem the right approach.

Comment: Thanks so much for all 3 answers.  I liked the cte approach in concept, but it didn't work for me (likely something I did wrong, I assume).  In the end DavidN's solution was easy to understand and performed well on about 20K rows of data.  Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
select s.[Date], coalesce(d2.LaborDeptid,d1.LaborDeptid) [LaborDept], sum(s.Sales) [TotalSales]
from Sales s
join Departments d1 on s.SalesDept = d1.AssociatedSalesDept
left join Departments d2 on d1.RollUpTo = d2.LaborDeptid
group by s.[Date], coalesce(d2.LaborDeptid,d1.LaborDeptid)
```

Answer (score 2):

I had to think about this one a bit, but here is one solution:

```
WITH cte AS (
SELECT CASE WHEN RollUpTo = 0 THEN LaborDeptId ELSE RollUpTo END AS LaborDeptId, AssociatedSalesDept
FROM departments)

SELECT s.date, d.LaborDeptid, SUM(s.Sales) AS TotalSales
FROM Sales s 
INNER JOIN cte d ON s.SalesDept = d.AssociatedSalesDept
GROUP BY s.date, d.LaborDeptid
```

Comment: In my tests, this one was a bit better than DavidN's because it had only one read to each table, instead of reading the department table twice.

Answer (score 1):

```
    SELECT s.Date, 
           d.LaborDeptId,
           SUM(Sales) + ISNULL((SELECT 
                            CASE Departments.RollUpTo
                                WHEN 0 THEN SUM(0)
                                ELSE SUM(Sales)
                            END
                          FROM Departments
                    INNER JOIN Sales ON Departments.AssociatedSalesDept = Sales.SalesDept
                         WHERE Departments.RollUpTo = d.LaborDeptId
                           AND Departments.RollUpTo <> 0
                      GROUP BY Departments.RollUpTo), 0) AS TotalSales
      FROM Departments d 
INNER JOIN Sales s ON d.AssociatedSalesDept = s.SalesDept
     WHERE d.RollUpTo = 0
  GROUP BY s.Date, d.LaborDeptId, d.RollUpTo;
```

Another option using a subquery.  I like DavidN's better though.